# Unterschied zwischen "abbezahlen" und "abzahlen"

Tags: synonym

Was ist korrekt (oder häufiger im Gebrauch): einen Kredit abbezahlen oder abzahlen? 
Falls beides möglich ist, wo ist der Unterschied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laut Duden sind [abzahlen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abzahlen) und [abbezahlen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abbezahlen) Synonyme.

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl würde ich sie auch weitgehend synonym verwenden, der einzige Unterschied ist, dass für mich

- **abzahlen** ein wenig mehr Gewicht auf den Prozess des Zurückzahlens über einen *Zeitraum* legt,
- **abbezahlen** dagegen Befreiung von der ausstehenden Schuld, also das *Ziel* im Blick hat.

Da allerdings der Prozess der Rückzahlung zum Ziel der Schuldenfreiheit führt, kann man den Unterschied fast ignorieren - und im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch ist das auch oft so.

Comment: Ein Händler kann bezahlt werden, eine Zahlung an den Händler kann gezahlt werden. Ich denke da liegt ein Unterschied, aber ob daraus auf ab- und ab-be-zahlen geschlossen werden kann, weiß ich nicht. Das ist wohl nur im juristischen Sinn entscheident.

Comment: Wiktionary gibt meinem letzten Kommentar teilweise recht, [s. 5. wenn dort noch nicht editiert](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/be-): Die Vorsilbe *be-* betont unter Umständen transitive Eigenschaften.